# Prove that $A^T + A$ is symmetric for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that $A^T + A$ is symmetric for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$.
So I understand how matrix Transpose works but I'm not sure if there is an example I can use to prove that this works for ANY $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: hint $(A^T)^T=A$ also $A+B=B+A$

Comment: Let the $(i,j)$ entry in $A$ be denoted by $a_{ij}$. The $(i,j)$-element of $A^\top$ is $a_{j,i}$. Then let $C=A+A^\top$. Then if the $(i,j)$ entry in $C$ is $c_{ij}$, it is $c_{ij}=a_{ij}+a_{ji}=c_{ji}$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following identity:

> $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$

Now apply it:
$$ (A^T+A)^T=(A^T)^T+A^T=A+A^T.$$
A matrix is symmetric if it equals its transpose. Matrix addition is commutative, and so:
$$ A^T+A=A+A^T=(A^T+A)^T.$$
Thus, $A^T+A$ is a symmetric matrix for any $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1):

A square matrix $M$ is symmetric if (by definition) it coincides with its transpose, i.e. if $M^T=M$.

Now, if $M=A^T+A$, we have that
$$
M^T=(A^T+A)^T=(A^T)^T+A^T=A+A^T=M\;\;\;\;,
$$
where the second equality above, follows by linearity of the operator of transposition, and the third one follows because such operator is involutory.