# For any square matrix $A$, prove that $\dfrac {1}{2} (A+A^{T})$ is symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any square matrix $A$, prove that $\dfrac {1}{2} (A+A^{T})$ is symmetric.

My Attempt:

Let us consider a matrix $A$ as:
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&2 \\
3&4 
\end{array}\right),
$$
Then,
$$
\dfrac {1}{2} (A+A^{T})=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&5/2 \\
5/2&4 
\end{array}\right),
$$.
This is symmetric. But How can I prove it without considering an example matrix?

Comment: $A+A^T$ is symmetric, not skew-symmetric. $A-A^T$ on the other hand...

Comment: Skew-symmetry? Come on... That is just the *excuse*.

Comment: Besides the 1/2, a duplicate of
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666260/prove-that-at-a-is-symmetric-for-any-n-times-n-matrix-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: an example wouldn't be sufficient to prove the property in general, although you could still start from an example to get a better feeling for the property you're trying to show.

The property is easy to prove if you know that:

- $\left(A^T\right)^T = A$
- $\left(A+B\right)^T = A^T+B^T$

Use this on $X = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(A+A^T \right)$ to find that $X^T = X$, and thus $X$ is symmetric.

> $X^T = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(A+A^T \right)^T = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(A^T+\left(A^T\right)^T \right) = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(A^T+A \right) = \ldots$

---

Alternatively, if you don't know or can't use these properties of matrix transpose, you can go via the matrix elements. Write $a_{ij}$ for the element on position $(i,j)$ of $A$, then the element $x_{ij}$ of the matrix $X = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(A+A^T \right)$ is ... Compare this with the element on position $(j,i)$, $x_{ji}$.

Comment: I understood the properties but couldnot use them in proof? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein See addition (hidden; hoover over); can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X = \frac{1}{2}( A + A^\top)$ isn't symmetric. Then we expect $X^\top - X \ne 0$

But ...

> $$ X^\top - X = \left( \frac{1}{2}( A + A^\top) \right)^\top - \left( \frac{1}{2}( A + A^\top) \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(A^\top+A-A-A^\top  \right) = 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

To prove a matrix A is symmeric, you just need to prove

$$A^T=A$$

So

$$(\dfrac{1}{2}(A+A^T))^T = \dfrac{1}{2}(A^T+(A^T)^T) = \dfrac{1}{2}(A^T+A)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

A matrix is symmetric if and only if it is equal to its transpose; skew-symmetric if and only if it equal to the opposite of its transpose.